# JSPerf, For Loop vs While Loop

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Hey guys can anyone tell me why my code in this JSPerf seems to indicate that a for loop is actually faster than a while loop?

I even decrease the value toward zero, and `for` still seems to outperform?

http://jsperf.com/html-canvas-performance

For the record, I'm making an HTML / Canvas game and I need to iterate through entities for rendering purposes.

**EDIT** : Code -
**EDIT** In case it's not clear what the problem is; " `for` still seems to outperform?"

```
  Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
    var e = [];
    var i = 100;
    while(i--) e.push(Math.random() * -1 << 1);
  };

  Benchmark.prototype.teardown = function() {
    e.length = 0;
  };

//WHILE
var i = e.length;
while(i--) e[i] *= 123;

//FOR
for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) e[i] *= 123;
```

Comment: Post the code here, please

Comment: I suspect the JS compiler has an optimization that detects common `for` loop idioms.

Comment: I figured it might be my browser too.. Any way to test across multiple?

Comment: In my browser Chrome 47, `for` is 17% faster than `while`

Comment: Unfortunately, I too am using Chrome 47, with similar results

Comment: I'm sorry, are you not able to read @meagar or are you just having a bad day? "Why isn't *THIS* code as performant as *THAT* code is quite a clear problem statement, and a link to a JSPerf which runs *itself* is about as clear as you can get when it comes to reproduction. Am I taking crazy pills here or are you rep farming? - Due to the nature of the question, code *in the question itself* would not be useful toward the answer as it would then be machine-specific...try not to get too caught up in the rules, the point is usefulness.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson You haven't actually included a short, self-contained, complete example in your code. You've included *some* code, but there is no way for us to actually execute it without relying on an external page. Please re-read the close reason: *...must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself.** Questions which depends on off-site links for meaning are off-topic here.

Comment: See also: [Flagging link-only questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276635/4639281)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like accessing array backwards is slow, but not because of while.

http://jsperf.com/html-canvas-performance/3

same performance with following code for me.

```
var i = 0, z = e.length;
while(i < z) e[i++] *= 123;
```

Comment: Please include some relevant data in your answer. As it stands, your answer isn't actually an answer, it's just a link to an off-site resource.

Comment: That's actually quite interesting, because it goes against what has been previously understood as good practice

Comment: @meagar Just like the question.

Comment: @meagar, I added the code I have modify there since my first revision, What is the problem?

Comment: Uh.. the question is pretty clear, includes code, and is well formatted.

Comment: @YOU I have no idea what your answer is without opening your jsperf.com link. Does it show that your code is faster, slower, or the same?

Comment: @meagar, I said **same perf** too. I can't post the result from jsperf, since it is my machine specific. or it is what you expected?

Comment: These guys are savages, I actually appreciate the time you took. Thanks @YOU , and whoever is upvoting meagar, please, dismount your high horse.

Comment: I also get the same performance with his test as the `for` loop. I agree that the performance hit comes from accessing the array backwards.